# Need to replace <style type="text/css"> using sed in Windows

Tags: html, sed, styles, package.json

I am using `sed` in `package.json` file to substitute the text.

But it does not replace the content.

Please help me solve this issue. I am using windows 10 and already installed `sed` (GNU sed version 4.2.1)

```
"replace": "sed -i \"s/<style type=\"text\\/css\">/<style type=\"text\\/css\" data-premailer=\"ignore\">/g\" ./dist/news.html"
```

Comment: What is the code you show? The content of your `json` file?

Comment: Yes, it is in the package.json file. It is inside "scripts": { } property. need to use like "npm run replace" or "yarn replace"

Comment: Hmm, I am not familiar with this but for sure you cannot quote your sed script with double quotes and have also double quotes in the expressions it uses. Try maybe to single-quote your sed script (`sed -i '...' ./dist/news.html`). And you can simplify it by using another `s` delimiter than slash: `sed -i 's!<style type=\"text/css...!<style type=\"text/css...!g'`. This will save you all slash escaping.

Comment: Suggesting to use `awk` instead of `sed` . Using awk you can use single quote `'`

Comment: Thanks, Renaud. With single-quote it returned an error. "The system cannot find the file specified." When use \"s/<style>/Some content/g\" it works. I think there is an issue with type=\"text\\/css\".

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try `awk` `gsub()` function instead of `sed`. `awk` use single quote.

I hope `'` will prevent expansion of all `"` in `gsub()` function.

```
   "replace": "awk '{gsub("<style type=\"text\\/css\">","<style type=\"text\\/css\" data-premailer=\"ignore\">");print}' ./dist/news.html"
```

#### Note that:

- `\\` is treated differently in `awk`. You might need `\\\\`
- The output/result is not in the same file (`sed -i` not possible) but sent to  `stdout`. You might want to do file redirection with `>` .

  ```
  "replace": "awk '{gsub("<style type=\"text\\/css\">","<style type=\"text\\/css\" data-premailer=\"ignore\">");print}' ./dist/news.html > ./dist/news.1.html"
  ```

#### Worst case:

You can always create a batch script `replace.bat` to pack your scripts:

##### `replace.bat`

```
  sed -i "s/<style type=\"text\\/css\">/<style type=\"text\\/css\" data-premailer=\"ignore\">/g\" %1
```

##### package.json

```
 ...
 "replace": "cmd.exe -c 'replace.sh ./dist/news.html' "
 ...
```

### Windows note:

In windows you can use `powershell` [`replace` cmdlets](https://www.kittell.net/code/powershell-unix-sed-equivalent-change-text-file/) instead of `sed`.

Also if you are comfortable with Linux, [install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) windows `wsl` subsystem and work in Linux environment.

Comment: _Suggesting to try awk gsub() function instead of sed. awk use single quote_: sed or awk do not "_use single quotes_". They both have arguments and among arguments they have scripts. It is the shell that "_use single (or double) quotes_" to delimit words. So enclosing the sed or awk scripts in single or double quotes is needed such that the shell parse them as single words. Anyway, there is no difference here between awk and sed about quotes. You could use single or double quotes with both... if you know how the shell handles all this, of course.